# Modify component specific state ( not registered on redux store ) inside a saga

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

Noob here, just learning React , React Redux and Redux Saga.

I stumbled upon a particular scenario.

Consider:

I have a ToDo app, obviously this app is composed of various components.
**There is a specific state that is purely for a specific component only.** (this will be the kicker)

Ex. **mode** in this case. Basically it determines how to display a specific todo item ( **edit mode** or **normal mode** ).

Now I am using redux saga to take care all of my codes that will cause side effects ( ajax processes in this case ).

Now if i click the edit button of a list item, i set that specific list item mode state to edit, which changes the appearance of the list item to text box to allow editing the list item title.

It will also display a new buttons , save button to save the changes and cancel button to cancel the changes and revert to normal mode.

After editing the title, i can click the save button, when I click the save button, it will fire an action which my root saga listens ( **EDIT_TODO** )
my root saga then picks up the action and routes to the appropriate worker saga to do the actual editing of the todo item ( involves ajax request )

**now this is where the culprit is**

I want to do a specific action only if the ajax operation is successful ( **if editing is successful done via ajax** ) and that is change the state of the list item to normal from edit.

how do I do that inside the saga?

**There are 2 ways actually.**

**1.) Make all your app state as a state on your redux store so you can just create actions in which your sagas (and other components) can just fire an action and your component will act on it if it is changed.**

This approach is ok only to a certain degree, yes there might be a state that is generaly shared across your components, but there are also state that is very specific only to a specific component.

On those cases it does not make sense to just add that very specific state to the redux store just so the sagas can fire an action for it.

**2.) Include a function call back on the action payload.**

So in my ex. when save button is clicked, when i fire the appropriate action that my root saga is listening, i will include a callback that will set the list item to normal mode.

Then inside the saga that is actually doing the editing of the todo item, when the ajax operation is good, call that callback.

To clarify, the callback that I passed along with the action payload, is a callback that only alter that local state of that specific component ( **mode** )

All global states ( registered on redux store ) are all altered via the reducers only.

For me, mentally it doesn't feel right? I don't know but sagas are just generators right and the purpose of generators in the context of asynchronous programming is to make asynchronous looking code to make it look synchronous to some degree (**very basic analogy of generators there**) and doing this callback thing dont feel right to me? or doesn't fit well with this approach? or kind of like breaks the purpose of generators ( sagas )?

I know it might help me to think that , that callback is just part of the data or payload of that action and not to think about it as a callback, but still doesn't feel right for me at least.

Or am I just being picky here?

**So is there an alternative to this aside from the above?**

I guess my question is,

**Is there , a way to make a component listen to an action? then if that action is fired wherever from any component or sagas, that action will be picked up by that specific component then that specific component will alter its specific state in return?**

Im not sure if that question make sense, or that is the proper way to phrase it. Im just a newbie to the subject so please go easy on me.

Thanks in advace.

Answer (score -1):

One of the really cool things of sagas is that you can either hook many sagas to one action but then you can also dispatch other actions from one saga. Let's say your EDIT_TODO (I'd rename this to UPDATE_TODO and use EDIT_TODO when kicking the edit mode) action fires the update saga below.

```
export function* update(api, action) {
  const { item } = action;
  const response = yield call(api.update, item)
  if (response.data) {
    // Dispatches action for success EDIT_TODO_SUCCESS
    yield put(updateSuccededActionCreator(item));
  } else {
    const error = response.error;
    // Dispatches action for success EDIT_TODO_FAILURE
    yield put(updateFailedActionCreator(item));
  }
}
```

Another thing to clarify, you can use the combineReducers redux api to "merge" different slices into one store. So you can design your store in the way you want, and a slice can just hold data for a specific part of your app. Something like:

```
const reducer = combineReducers({
  todoState: todoReducer,
  sessionState: sessionReducer
});
```

Comment: I think your answer belongs to the number 1.) solution I have above. So basically storing the state to the redux store so inside saga i can just fire an action after the ajax operation is successful. I was wondering if there is an alternative to 1 and 2 options ive highlighted above.

Comment: Also i opted on using the number 2.) solution, the call back, as it would not make much sense to store the state to the global redux store as the state is very specific only to that specific component.

Comment: I disagree. You have smart/connected components and dumb/presentational components. A very small component that is fairly trivial should not be connected to redux, but it can receive the mutation through props. If you use a callback, you are completely breaking the paradigm.

Comment: You are entitled to your own opinion. Please re-read my explanation on solution 1.) above and why it is useful for me to a certain degree and what degree it does not make sense again for me. Specifically, adding a state that is very specific to a certain specific component to the global redux store just so a saga can fire an action for it.

Comment: Again my question is, is there any other ways to accomplish my goal? your answer belongs to the solution 1 already i have above.

Comment: You are right, you can take the approach you want. But there's no need to use redux or redux-sagas at all for the approach you are taking. You can just use a promise directly in your component to make the network call. The redux-sagas is a side-effect library for redux. And redux should only mutate the state through a reducer, which is a pure function. Otherwise, the predictable, one-way flow of redux is broken and there's no purpose in using it.

Comment: Yeah i understand that but I think it is alright for other components to have their own local states right? I mean , every state of a component is not required to be registered on the redux store. Each component can have their own state given that state is only localized for them and does not affect other components ( as per my example above ). I think this is acceptable design. And I think that is not enough reasoning to drop redux and redux saga entirely just because a component have a local state that is not registered on the global redux store.

Comment: again i am not satisfied to the approach i took, as per my explanation on solution no. 2.) that is why i asked maybe there is a better way of doing this aside from the 2 solutions I've highlighted above.

Comment: I did not mean drop it for the whole project, but I meant you can drop it completely for the component. You can perfectly use the component own state and just let the component make the network calls directly without redux actions or redux sagas if you think that works for your use case.

Comment: Point taken, yeah that is certainly an option. So not use redux saga instead just use a raw generator function to handle async operation beautifully inside the component itself.

Comment: Or a Promise or async/await.